# Mystery how google makes borders half as thick but still set to 1 pixel

Tags: html, css

Its a mystery to me how the 1px borders around the cells of [this table](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=hockey+score&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU731AU731&oq=hockey+score&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i59.5108j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=lg;/g/11c2l9b6b6;7;/m/05gwr;mt;fp;1) are very thin, but if I copy the exact style:

```
border-right: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
border-bottom: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
```

It looks twice as thick. I cant see anything thats causing these borders to look nicer and sharper. Why are they thinner?

**EDIT:**
We worked out that google has somehow made the 1px border to 0.5px, it doesnt matter how, you can just set it:

```
border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
```

I have a small screen laptop with very high resolution (high pixel density), so I can see the difference between the half and one pixel borders here: https://jsfiddle.net/pd9hkd4j/2/

Most people in tech / gaming spheres do have a full HD screen / monitor, but also have a larger screen and therefore slightly lower pixel density, so their monitor does not render 0.5px and 1px differently.

It may be that Google has not intentionally tried to have a thinner border, and its just a circumstance of a minority of screens.

Comment: 1pixel is 1pixel, in all websites, including google.

Comment: Except that it is not being rendered that way.

Comment: I have a 15" 4K screen where I can clearly see the difference, but cannot see it in my 27" 4K screen. I can see the difference in my 27" only if I change the zoom (ctrl + mouse wheel). So I think this is just a matter of screen scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very bright `border-color` on a white `background`. Maybe you try to set the `border-color` to a different `background-color`? [panther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595669/panther) is correct with his comment, `1px` is `1px`, but with some optical tricks, you can make the `border` *appear* thinner, than it actually is.

Take a quick look at the example below: Both `<div>` at the top contain a `<div>` with the same `border-color` and thickness. But the one on the black background seems to be much thicker, since the contrast between the `border` and the `background` is very high.

On the bottom there is a white background with some different borders, and you will probably notice, that the lighter ones look thinner, than the dark ones. It is just an optical trick, Google is using to play with the appearance :-)

**Edit:**

It turned out, that [o0o0o0o0o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7408217/o0o0o0o0o) actually has a high DPI Display, which is able to display "half pixels" since `1px` width is not necessarily equal to *one pixel* of the display on high DPI Settings. So you actually **can** set the border width to a float value, but it obviously will only be visible to users with higher DPI Displays. A "regular" Monitor will show it as `1px`, since its not possible to display half pixels (which also is kind of obvious ;) )

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}

.border {
  border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  clear: both;
  background: white;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 60px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bottom div {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.border-10 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.border-30 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.border-50 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
}

.border-70 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
}
.border-90 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #383838;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper black">
  <div class="border">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper white">
  <div class="border">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="border-10"></div>
  <div class="border-30"></div>
  <div class="border-50"></div>
  <div class="border-70"></div>
  <div class="border-90"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, its definitely thinner. I used the exact style in the exact same way. I do know that I can set the background to a light grey under the white cells, and set 1px margins between the cells to inconsistently achieve what google does but they use borders which would be better.

Comment: Could you provide a screnshot or something verifiable? If I click your link from my country, I don't see any table at all. I tried it with my local sports table, and there it was 1px

Comment: Try this link
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=hockey+score&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU731AU731&oq=hockey+score&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=T0oqWsGlG4is0ATVsaXoBQ

in google chrome. I think also my screen is high resolution and small (high pixel density). That might contribute to it. I just realised too I can set border to 0.5px or anything less than one.

Comment: Nope, no table for me

Comment: Thats unfortunate maybe go onto google.com.au and then search 'hockey score'

I think google has some style in there like width 50% or the table layout thats causing the thinner border. In any case if you have a 1px border and change it to 0.5px it has the effect I'm talking about.

Comment: Also gives me only some serach results, but no table =/ If I set 0.5px to a border, it still appears as 1px. Do you have kind of a retine display with higher DPI settings or something?

Comment: Thats really weird. The hockey score thing is just one of the things google does now, like when u search 5 + 5 and a calculator comes up in results. But yeah

Comment: Ok here https://jsfiddle.net/pd9hkd4j/

Yes I have 13'3 inch laptop full HD so its 'retina'

For me the first rectangle has half border width.
Woops changed link

Comment: Ok, I have a 24" FHD TFT and both borders appear the same for me :-) Mystery solved, I guess

Comment: Ok well its good to know that most of my users wont see the thin border anyway. Thanks dude for persisting